# Where is CDbCriteria in Yii2 framework?

Tags: yii2

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = 'categoryMaster_id=:categoryMaster_id';
```

I want to get data from multiple tables and show in one JSON. I'm getting error here:

> Class 'app\controllers\CDbCriteria' not found.

Comment: More background please.

Comment: Please explain more about your problem.

Comment: There is no `CDbCriteria` in Yii2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `CDbCriteria` in Yii2 - it was mostly replaced by [`Query`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query) and [`ActiveQuery`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery). You should read [Query Builder](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder) section (and related) in documentation, and [upgrade instructions](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/intro-upgrade-from-v1#query-builder).

But you probably need something like:

```
$data = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->from('my_table')
    ->leftJoin('my_joined_table', 'my_joined_table.my_id = my_table.id')
    ->where('categoryMaster_id=:categoryMaster_id', ['categoryMaster_id' => $id])
    ->all();
```

Comment: worked for me! thanks, getting error for left join. working on it